# Trim a field name in angularjs that is defined in json file

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a field name in JSON file.

JSON file is:

```
Data_underscore:1,
Datawithoutunderscore:2,
Data space:3        //error
```

I create a table in angular JSON than how I pickup value of 3rd one (Data space)

my code is

```
<tr>                                                
<td>{{ x.Data_underscore}}</td>      //print 1
<td>{{ x.Datawithoutunderscore}}</td> //print 2
<td>{{ x.Data space}}</td>              //error
</tr>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can access it using the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) like:

```
<td>{{ x['Data space'] }}</td>
```

Answer (score -2):

The only way to solve it to use bracket notation.

```js
var test = {
    "id": "109",
    "No. of interfaces": "4"
}
alert(test["No. of interfaces"]);
```